# How to find elements in a list satisfying different criteria

Tags: list-manipulation

I am not good at *Mathematica*.
I have the following list already ordered according to the second part:

```
list1 = {{3, 2}, {5, 2}, {7, 2}, {7, 4}, {8, 4}, {12, 8}, {94, 8}, {4, 10}, {42, 10}};
```

I want to select the first elements where the second part gets bigger. The result would be:

```
list2 = {{3, 2}, {7, 4}, {12, 8}, {4, 10}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach goes like this:

```
First /@ GatherBy[list1, Last]
```

It turns out that [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) can be replaced by [`SplitBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user57467 Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html):

```
SequenceReplace[list1, {p : ({_, a_} ..)} :> First[{p}]]
```

> {{3, 2}, {7, 4}, {12, 8}, {4, 10}}

Comment: This function is still not included in my version. I will study it in the future. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list1, Last]
```

> {{3, 2}, {7, 4}, {12, 8}, {4, 10}}